# How to filter a List<MyObject> where at least a property have a match?

Tags: .net, linq

I've a list of Object such as:

```
var data = ctx.Clinics.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(p => p.Name).Select(p => new
{
    ID = p.ID,
    Name = p.Name,
    Region = p.Regions.Description,
    City = p.City,
    Address = p.Address,
    Phone = p.Phone,
    InterestPassive = p.InterestPassive,
    InterestGlad = p.InterestGlad,
    Gross = p.Activities.Where(e => e.Converted.HasValue && e.Converted.Value && e.DateActivity.HasValue).Sum(s => (decimal?)s.FirstEstimate) ?? 0,
    DiscountApplied = p.Activities.Where(e => e.Converted.HasValue && e.Converted.Value && e.DateActivity.HasValue && e.Discount != null).Sum(e => (e.FirstEstimate / 100) * e.Discount) ?? 0,
}).ToList();
```

which is a result set for a DataTable.

On this list, I'd like to apply a filter on every property of the list which "contains" a input string (such as free textbox that will search everywhere in a grid):

```
string searchTerm = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]").FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there a way on LINQ to search a value for every property within a list of Objects?

Comment: I have created a view in the database that concatenates all fields into a single string when trying to solve similar issues. Alternatively, use something like LINQKit with Reflection to build  an expression for `Where` that tests every field with `Contains`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using Reflection, and you intend to search all public properties, you can use the following extensions to do a `Contains` search against every public property:

```
public static class IQueryableEFExt {
    #region Predicates
    // findTerm - string that must be contained by any property
    // r => s => r.AllPropertyValues().Any(pv => pv.ToString().Contains(findTerm))
    public static Func<T, bool> IsAnyContains<T>(string findTerm) => r => r.AnyPropertyContains(findTerm);
#endregion
#region Where
    // findTerm - string that must be contained by any property
    // dbq.Where(r => r.AllPropertyValues().Any(pv => pv.ToString().Contains(findTerm)))
    public static IEnumerable<T> WhereAnyContains<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, string findTerm) => src.Where(IsAnyContains<T>(findTerm));
#endregion
#region OrderBy
    // findTerm - string that must be contained by any property
    // dbq.OrderBy(r => r.AllPropertyValues().Any(pv => pv.ToString().Contains(findTerm)) ? 1 : 2)
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderByAnyContains<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, string findTerm)
        => src.OrderBy(r => IsAnyContains<T>(findTerm)(r) ? 1 : 2);

    // findTerm - string that must be contained by any property
    // dbq.OrderByDescending(r => r.AllPropertyValues().Any(pv => pv.ToString().Contains(findTerm)) ? 1 : 2)
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderByLikeAnyDescending<T>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, string findTerm)
        => dbq.OrderByDescending(r => IsAnyContains<T>(findTerm)(r));
#endregion
}
```

This code depends on a custom extension method:

```
public static bool AnyPropertyContains<T>(this T anObject, string substr) => typeof(T).GetProperties().Any(pf => pf.GetValue(anObject).ToString().Contains(substr));
```

If a little performance is important to you, you could refactor to cache the return value of `GetProperties()` to not do that lookup every time.

You would use it like:

```
var ans = data.WhereAnyContains(searchTerm);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can select you're object into a dictionary rather than a strongly typed class, that would help you out

```cs
var data = /* ... */ .Select(p => new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    [nameof(p.Id)] = p.Id,
    [nameof(p.Name] = p.Name
    ...
}

var filtered = data.Where(d => d.Values.OfType<string>().Contains("searchTerm"));
```

An alternative way is reflection.

```cs
var data = /* database call */
var properties = data.Where(d => typeof(d).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string) && ((string)p.GetValue(d)).Contains("searchTerm"))
```